# Year-month-week expression

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a data written in specific expression. To simplify the data, here is the example I made:

```
df<-data.frame(date=c(2012034,2012044,2012051,2012063,2012074),
               math=c(100,100,23,46,78))
```

`2012034` means 4th week of march,2012. Likewise `2012044` means 4th week of April,2012. I was trying to make the values of `date` expressing some order. The reason why I have to do this is because when I don't change them to time expressions, x axis of the scatter plot looks really weird.

My goal is this:
Find the oldest date in `date` column and name it as 1. In this case, `2012034` should be `1`. Next, find the second oldest date in `date` column and  calculate how many weeks passed after that `date`. The second oldest date in `date` is `2012044`.So, 5 weeks after the oldest date `2012034`. So it should be changed as 1+5=6. So, likewise, I want to number the `date` to indicate how many weeks have passed since the oldest `date`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I clarified what I want to do. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is by also specifying the day of the week and subtract it at the end, i.e.

```
as.Date(paste0(df$date, '-1'), '%Y%m%U-%u') - 1
#[1] "2012-03-22" "2012-04-22" "2012-05-01" "2012-06-15" "2012-07-22"
```

Comment: I think I can use the method you suggested!